# check if object has key in Typescript and use that key

Tags: typescript, object, casting, key, hasownproperty

I have the following code:

```js
let show = {
    createTag: false,
    updateFeature: false,
    createFeatureGroup: false,
    deleteFeature: false,
    deleteCycle: false,
};
```

And I'm getting a value from the querystring that I want to match agains the keys of show.

The following code works ok, but I want a way to let Typescrpt infer it and avoid having to issue the cast:

```js
const showDialog = $page.query.get('show') || '';

if (showDialog && showDialog in show) {
    // I want to get rid of the "<keyof typeof show>" cast
    show[<keyof typeof show>showDialog] = true; 
}
```

I though that just issueing `showDialog in show` typescript would know that inside that `if` showDialog is a key of `show`, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: `in` narrowing only works with string literals: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create a type guard:

```
function isValidParam(k: string): k is keyof typeof show {
  return k in show;
}

const showDialog = $page.query.get('show') || '';

if (isValidParam(showDialog)) {
    show[showDialog] = true; 
}
```

but you decide if it's worth it. I'd probably just keep the cast, personally.

Answer (score 15):

The type guard presented by @paolostyle is very specific to the `show` object. The following snippet is more generic and can be used for any key in any object:

```js
export function isKeyOfObject<T>(
  key: string | number | symbol,
  obj: T,
): key is keyof T {
  return key in obj;
}
```

Comment: I had to change this to `isKeyOfObject<T extends object>` — probably due to Typescript version differences?